# How do I know if robocopy skipped the file I am copying?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am using a batch file to copy a database backup file using robocopy (on Windows 7/2008) and need to restore (with replace) the database only after the backup file is really changed (not skipped by robocopy).

```
robocopy \\server\share . foo.bak /TBD /NP
```

Tried testing errorlevel but it doesn't help. Anyone has some suggestion to achieve such objective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A bit inelegant I admit, but write a log file and then parse it?

Comment: Not at all inelegant. Robocopy has a number of options for logging: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: +1. Exactly, use Robocopy's logging options.